# How to reference the default Id property of an entity on google app engine

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

If i've annotated a string variable in my JDO to be used as the id e.g.

```
@Id
private String nameOfId;
```

And in the appengine's console it's named as 'NAME/ID', what do I use to get the property

Note: For my queries, I'm using the datastore's query and not the entity manager, this means a collection of entities are returned to me and i've to get it's properties using, 'getProperty("propertyName")'

Also Note: ive tried the following names

```
getProperty("id");
getProperty("Id");
getProperty("name");
getProperty("NAME");
getProperty("NAME/ID");
getProperty("nameOfId");
```

none of these worked, I would just like to know what text I need to put as my argument for the getProperty method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ID is not a property of the entity, it is a part of the entity key.  It appears in the Console as a column only to help identify the entity.

To get the string ID from a `com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity`, call its `getKey()` method to return a `Key`, and call the key's `getName()` method.